# Драйвера видеокарты

Tags: linux, драйвер, nvidia

Хочу поставить драйвера от Nvidia (которые с подержкой Vulkan).

1. Выхожу из сессии
2. ctrl+alt+f1
3. sudo servise lightdm stop
4. sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-355.00.27.run
5. .....установка
6. sudo servise lightdm start
7. sudo reboot

Потом наблюдаю бесконечный экран с Underscore ( _ ).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как поставить дрова?!

Что делаю не так ?!

Линк на [дрова](https://developer.nvidia.com/vulkan-driver)

Comment: Может стоит подождать драйвера в репозитории?

Comment: Предлагаете до апреля ждать?! (16,04 релиз Mir)

Comment: А что вот прям щас поддерживает вулкан? Из-за чего надо вот прям сейчас переходить на новое?

Comment: Хочется
1.Полазить по демкам
2.Выучить API

Comment: Какая версия дистрибутива? Какая видюха?

Comment: Пробывал с дебианом 8 и убунту LTS (14.04.03),
GT640

Comment: Попробуй не с лтс.

Comment: Так поддержка заявлена что на LTS тоже можно ставить...